# How long does it take before a new question appears on my profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I asked a question [Sharepoints use of the ads wwwhomepage attr](https://serverfault.com/questions/264420/sharepoint-and-use-of-ads-wwwhomepage-attribute) about 3 hours ago.  I came back to see if there was an answer.  I mean come on, thats the point right?  Impatience!

Anyway, I did not remember what I called the question, so I clicked on my name in the upper bar, went to my profile and list of Questions, and did not see it.  So doubting myself I went to Stack Overflow in case I posted it there.  No joy.

Finally searched on it here and found it.  I guess I am asking how often the update to profiles runs?  I know that the badge calculation takes measurable time (5 minutes or so) from experiments. (So many new Stack Exchange sites, I usually get two or three badges from each for the basic stuff, and the delay is pretty common and consistent).  But I had not noticed this lag before.

Not saying it is a problem either, mostly curious what the update cycle looks like, since I used to think it was a query run each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually they appear almost immediately for me.

Do make sure that you have the correct sort order set in your profile.  If you are sorting by votes or view, your new question may not appear in the first page of the list.  You should probably sorting by 'newest' if you want to see newly added questions.

I can imagine that it is somewhat cached, so you may need to do a force-reload in your browser.

Comment: Well la-dee-da...  That was my 11th question, and so it wrapped to the second page.  My mistake, thank you!

Comment: @geoff as we always say, the 11th question is the charm..